Как правильно закрыть окно без крестика, на кастомном окошке
Есть сервис окон в котором создается инстанс окна и для него ViewModel это все создается по запросу нужного окна обращаясь к сервису окон, в ходе создания пробрасывается window.Close во ViewModel, для этого во ViewModel в ctor имеется ctor(Action exitWindow), чтобы туда поместился метод закрытия окна.
Примерно такой код:
List<object> dependencies = _containerDi.Resolve(viewModel.Key, identifiers, arguments);
dependencies.Add(window.Close);
window.DataContext = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModel.Key, dependencies.ToArray());

Закрытие окна происходит не по крестику, а по отрисованной кнопке, так как окно кастомное и крестик убрал, команда просто вызывает метод exitWindow.
Можно ли, верно ли так если все это делает сервис окон или же нужно использовать какой-то другой подход/механизм?

Сервис нужен чтобы пробросить закрытие окон из VM в V. Задайте себе вопрос, нужно ли VM знать, что окно закрылось? Если да, надо к кнопке закрытия привязывать команду. Если нет, то вместо этого закрывайте окно просто внутри V, методом Window.Close.

@Vlad, не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. У меня во ViewModel команда, которая использует переданный метод Close(), чтобы закрыть окно, так как крестик убрал. Если я понял, то что вы сказали, то мне надо как-то из Vm управлять view, чтобы чтобы из VM произвести закрытие из View, как это можно реализовать или я вас не понял)

@Vlad, Я тут подумал, может во ViewModel прокидывать имплементацию, в которой имеется ссылка на окно, и из vm просто обращаюсь к методу имплементации, а сам метод уже вызывает метод закрытия окна, как правильнее?))

вьюмодель знать не знает ни про какие окна или какое то там закрытие. Она может: а) выставить значение у своего свойства какого то, назовем его...пусть bool DialogResult б) бросить событие. Окно может увидеть это и отреагировать. Чтобы каждый раз  не писать одно и то же в  OnLoaded можно сделать атачед свойство и прикреплять его к окну.

Одного не пойму, почему за "Закрытие окна происходит не по крестику, а по отрисованной кнопке" отвечает вдруг VM? Если вы переписали окно и хотите в этом окне кастомную кнопку закрытия, то это чисто View логика, которая должна быть реализована исключительно в данном окне. Сделали условную кнопку, подписались на Click, по его событию вызвали нужную логику самого окна, готово. Ну или вовсе, используйте стандартные команды, что-то вроде такого: <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />. В любом случае, при чем тут VM, не очень понимаю...

@EvgeniyZ Ну например, открываю окно ввожу кучу данных, нажимаю кнопку сохранить, команда во VM сначала обращается к репозиторию, чтобы отправить данные в бд, и как остаточная логика закрывает окошко.

Если речь про закрытие всего приложения, то обычно закрытие отлавливается в App.xaml.cs (переопределить к примеру OnExit) и там уже вызывается нужная логика, нужных VM, которые сохраняют свою работу. Если под каждое окно вам нужна логика закрытия, то яб это сделал все также, в "Сервисе окон", который подпишется на событие закрытие и вызовет нужную логику, нужной VM, ибо это не задача V оповещать о том, что она закрывается (ИМХО).

@EvgeniyZ Да обычные окошки их по приложению много и у каждой должна быть своя логика, что касается подписки в сервисе имеется ввиду при создании инстанса окна, подписаться на Closed или Closing, а подписывать методы репозитория созданного инстанса VieModel?

Типа того. Условно (псевдокод): class WindowsService { Dictionary<IViewModel, IWindow> _windows; Open(IViewModel vm) { var window = _windows[vm]; windows.DataContext = vm; window.OnClose += vm.Dispose(); window.Show(); } } Код от балды, но суть думаю уловили. Можете пойти в обратном направлении, сделать метод "закрытия" в сервисе и в нем уже делать что-то такое: Close(IViewModel vm) {  var window = _windows[vm]; window.Close(); vm.Dispose(); } Как видите, за логику закрытия отвечает сам сервис, а уже и окно и VM вызывают свою, независимую друг от друга логику.

А понял, спасибо

Я так понимаю, без примера не обойтись... Чтож, давайте покажу пример. Но предупрежу, он будет очень кривой, но покажет суть того, что у вас +- должно быть.
И так, для начала нам нужно создать 2 интерфейса, которые будут реализовывать наши окна и VM слои, это будет как их идентификатор, по которому мы сможем ограничить наши методы (мы ведь не хотим в методе регистрации окна принимать что-то кроме окна, верно?). Собственно, создаем:
public interface IWindow {}
public interface IViewModel {}

Далее давайте создадим интерфейс самого сервиса, в нем мы пропишем всю логику, которая нас интересует, в моем примере это будет открытие, закрытие, ну и регистрация. Получаем такое:
public interface IWindowService
{
    void Show<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel;
    void Close<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel;
    void Register<TViewModel, TWindow>()
      where TViewModel : IViewModel
      where TWindow : class, IWindow;
}

Теперь мы можем написать сам сервис:

Метод регистрации - Его задача сохранить типы регистрируемых окон и VM, чтобы потом мы могли быстро их сопоставить и вызвать нужное окно. Пусть хранит все это в словаре, получаем в итоге такое:
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _windows = [];

public void Register<TViewModel, TWindow>() where TViewModel : IViewModel where TWindow : class, IWindow
{
    _windows.Add(typeof(TViewModel), typeof(TWindow));
}

Замечу то, что тут нет проверки на уже зарегистрированный тип, это сами сделаете если надо, моя задача показать сейчас максимально просто задумку.

Метод показа - Его задача состоит в том, чтобы по типу из контейнера достать нужный экземпляр окна и его VM, задать окну DataContext и показать само окно. В качестве контейнера я использую контейнер Microsoft (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), вы подстраивайте под себя:
public void Show<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel
{
    var windowType = _windows[typeof(TViewModel)];
    var window = services.GetService(windowType) as Window;
    var viewModel = services.GetService<TViewModel>();

    window.DataContext = viewModel;
    window.Show();
}

И опять, тут нету проверок на NULL, учитывайте это!

Метод закрытия - Очевидно, он отвечает за закрытие окна. Для этого нам надо взять из контейнера по типу нужный объект и вызвать у него .Close() метод.
public void Close<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel
{
    var windowType = _windows[typeof(TViewModel)];
    var window = services.GetService(windowType) as Window;
    window?.Close();
}



Весь код получается такой:
public class WindowService(IServiceProvider services) : IWindowService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _windows = [];

    public void Register<TViewModel, TWindow>() where TViewModel : IViewModel where TWindow : class, IWindow
    {
        _windows.Add(typeof(TViewModel), typeof(TWindow));
    }

    public void Show<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        var windowType = _windows[typeof(TViewModel)];
        var window = services.GetService(windowType) as Window;
        var viewModel = services.GetService<TViewModel>();

        window.DataContext = viewModel;
        window.Show();
    }
    public void Close<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        var windowType = _windows[typeof(TViewModel)];
        var window = services.GetService(windowType) as Window;
        window?.Close();
    }
}

Обратите внимание на то, что все методы завязаны на VM слоях, все методы просят именно VM, а не V (окна), по этим VM уже ищется окно. Это важно, ибо по правилам MVVM слой ViewModel не должен знать ничего про View и наоборот, ну а запрашивая окна, мы будем требовать в VM слое указывать V слой, что является нарушением.
Собственно, сервис у нас есть, дальше давайте для удобства создадим несколько методов расширения, которые сократят нам код:
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddView<TViewModel, TWindow>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TViewModel : class, IViewModel
        where TWindow : class, IWindow
    {
        services.AddSingleton<TViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<TWindow>();

        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceProvider RegisterView<TViewModel, TWindow>(this IServiceProvider services)
        where TViewModel : class, IViewModel
        where TWindow : class, IWindow
    {
        var service = services.GetService<IWindowService>();
        service?.Register<TViewModel, TWindow>();
        return services;
    }
}

Как видите, в методах расширения нет ничего магического, просто объединяем 2 вызова в один удобный метод. Но как по мне, это костыль, ибо 1. для регистрации нам надо вызвать 2 разных метода, что по сути можно было бы сделать в виде одного. 2. В методе регистрации постоянно дергается IWindowService, что в теории не очень хорошо (хотя я часто вижу подобное в других проектах).
Так, теперь регистрируем все в контейнер. Открываем класс App.xaml.cs и переопределяем OnStartup, для примера пусть будет что-то такое:
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddSingleton<IWindowService, WindowService>();
    services.AddView<MainViewModel, MainWindow>();

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    provider.RegisterView<MainViewModel, MainWindow>();

    var windowService = provider.GetRequiredService<IWindowService>();
    windowService.Show<MainViewModel>();
}

Супер, остается только реализовать интерфейсы у окна и VM:
public partial class MainWindow : IWindow {...}

и
public partial class MainViewModel : IViewModel {...}

Ну и также, из-за того, что за старт окна теперь отвечаем мы, нам надо убрать в App.xaml свойство StartupUri. Все, теперь можем запускать, должно открыться окно.
Вот вам базовый сервис, который управляет окнами.

Теперь давайте поговорим про закрытие и выполнения логики в VM. Логично будет требовать через интерфейс реализации нужного нам метода в каждой VM, а затем, в методе закрытия, прописать вызов нужного метода. Собственно давайте так и сделаем.
Дописываем интерфейс VM:
public interface IViewModel 
{
    void OnClose();
}

Для того, чтобы не реализовывать везде этот метод, давайте сделаем абстрактный класс, который будет иметь базовую реализацию для всех VM и который можно будет переопределить:
public abstract class ViewModelBase : IViewModel
{
    public virtual void OnClose() { }
}

Теперь допишем метод Close нашего сервиса, в нем мы теперь будем запрашивать еще и VM, у которой вызовем метод закрытия.
public void Close<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : IViewModel
{
    var windowType = _windows[typeof(TViewModel)];
    var window = services.GetService(windowType) as Window;
    var viewModel = services.GetService<TViewModel>();
    viewModel?.OnClose();
    window?.Close();
}

Осталось дописать VM. Наследуем ее теперь не от интерфейса, а от абстрактного класса class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase. Заметьте, реализовывать метод не обязательно, вы можете запустить проект и все будет работать. Ну а если нам надо сделать что-то в VM при закрытие, то пишем override и выбираем метод OnClose, студия сгенерирует нам что-то такое:
public override void OnClose()
{
    
}

Собственно этот метод и будет теперь вызываться при закрытие окна. Ну а дальше уже ваша фантазия.
А да, закрыть окно вы можете из любого класса, который лежит в контейнере. Допустим, если хотим закрыть по клику кнопки, то запрашиваем IWindowService через конструктор и вызываем в команде кнопки windowService.Close<MainViewModel>();, все, окно закроется.

Недостатки:

Очевидный недостаток, дублируется код, я бы подумал как избавиться от этого. По хорошему тут стоит отказаться от словаря сопоставления в сервисе и через рефлексию искать VM и M через имена. Условно окно зовется MainWindow, VM под нее MainViewModel, вот Main тут уникальное, имея его, мы можем через рефлексию найти как VM так и окно.

Другой очевидный недостаток, это то, что окна регистрируются как синглтон, а это означает, что мы не можем открыть одно окно несколько раз. Чтоб избавиться от этого недостатка стоит наверно хранить открытые окна и их VM, ну и уже по этому "хранилищу" искать того, кого надо закрыть.



Собственно вот и все. Заметьте, что в моем коде VM и V отделены друг от друга, они независимы, про них знает только сервис, который ими и руководит. Также у меня нету создания объектов вручную, за это отвечает контейнер, у которого я просто прошу нужные мне объекты по типу. Ну и ключевое, повторю, в VM только VM слои, там нет чего-то по типу .Show<MainWindow>, ибо это окно, это View, чего быть не должно в VM.

Я уловил суть, спасибо огромное

Сделал, не трогая code behind, и закрывая окно из порождающего класса, то есть сервиса окон/представлений:

Когда вызываю окно, передаю его тип, создается инстанс окна, зависимости для Vm, сама Vm, устанавливается контекст и самое главное я регистрирую то, что окно создано в Dictionary<object, object> registryView = new(); для того, чтобы отлавливать ссылку на окно по ViewModel.
public ServiceView Window<View>(string[] identifiers = null, params object[] arguments) where View : Window
{
    window = Activator.CreateInstance<View>();
    var viewType = typeof(View);
    foreach (var viewModel in containerView)
    {
        if (viewModel.Value.Item1 == viewType)
        {
            List<object> dependencies = _containerDi.Resolve(viewModel.Key, identifiers, arguments);
            var vm = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModel.Key, dependencies.ToArray());
            window.DataContext = vm;
            registryView.Add(vm, window);
            break;
        }
     }
     return this;
}


В VM, получая сервис окон, мы обращаемся к его методу закрытия окна, и отправляем this - то есть vm, чтобы потом сопоставить в сервисе окон VM с окном и получить ссылку на окно из словаря:
 public MainViewModel(IServiceView serviceView)
 {
     Command2 = RaketaCommand.Launch(() =>
     {
         serviceView.Close(this);
     });
 }


Метод закрытия в сервисе окон:
public void Close(object viewModel)
{
    var view = registryView[viewModel];
    if(view is Window window)
    {
        window.Close();
        registryView.Remove(viewModel);
    }
}



По идее, все правильно, не использовал code behind, не использовал сильные связи, все абстрагировал и разделил ответственности.

Плохое решение, ибо V знает про VM, это нарушение. Если хотите такую передачу, то абстрагируйтесь от VM. Ну допустим, создайте интерфейс и поместите в него Action, будет что-то по типу interface IClosable { Action Close { get; } }, далее реализуйте его в VM (class MainVM : IClosable { public Action Close { get; } ... }), а дальше, проверьте у окна, является-ли DataContext этим интерфейсом, если да, то задайте его Close нужную логику, ну, что-то типа такого: if (DataContext is IClosable vm) { vm.Close += () => this.Close(); }. Все, в VM вызывайте Close?.Invoke(); и окно закроется.

А более правильным решением, как по мне, это отдать данную логику самому "сервису окон", который будет искать нужное окно и вызывать его метод Close(). В любом случае, View (окно) не должно ничего знать про другие слои, помните про это.

А во как понял понял, спасибо большое

Переделал ответ, теперь по идее максимально правильно))), абстрагировался от сильных связей, абстрагировался от окна(абстракция только на методе), не использовал code behind, разделил ответственности, надеюсь все хорошо)

Ну, тоже так себе решение. Зачем вам ICloseView closeView в VM мне не понятно. У вас ведь ServiceView знает все и про окно, и про VM этого окна, а значит он сам может там задать все, что ему надо. Поэтому передача .Close(closeView.ViewClose); - это, по сути, костыль. Также от if (dependency is ICloseView view) можно избавиться, унаследовав каждую VM окна от общего интерфейса или даже может абстрактного класса, в котором будет виртуальный метод закрытия. Тогда в нужной VM можно будет переопределить метод закрытия если надо, а в сервисе не будет лишних проверок.

Ну и последнее, что меня смущает, так это Activator.CreateInstance - зачем...? Если вы используете контейнер, то зарегистрируйте все VM и V в контейнер, а затем из него и забирайте нужные объекты. Зачем своя инициализация... Я не знаю)

Да.. че то я поторопился с лишним классом и разделением ответственности, надо будет переделать, а что касается Activator.CreateInstance, я просто регистрирую типы у меня сопоставления в словаре хранятся как Type что view, что viewmodel их инстансы создаются по запросу нужного окна, по идее так производительнее в самом начале программы так как не нужно хранить готовые объекты, а лишь получать когда необходимы)

Вы изобретаете свой контейнер этим CreateInstance, ну и как бы, зачем? Если уже есть контейнер, который также хранит типы и создает их по требованию. Вы вон в коде делаете _containerDi.Resolve() - вот под капотом там также условный словарь с типами и вызов CreateInstance. Другими словами, свой CreateInstance замените на еще один _containerDi.Resolve и зарегистрируйте все VM и V в основном контейнере.

И опять вы вернулись на стартовую позицию... Я вам ведь кучу раз уже сказал, что View не должна знать ничего про VM, как и VM не должна знать ничего про View. Ну а теперь взгляните на свой код - Window<View>...View : Window - то есть, по вашей логике, для открытия окна в VM слое, надо сделать service.Window<MainWindow>(..);, где MainWindow - это VIew. Вы понимаете в чем тут проблема? Весь ваш сервис должен оперировать VM слоями, где вы передаете в условный View метод конкретный VM тип, по которому ищется уже зарегистрированное окно и выводится.

То есть я просто переписываю логику так чтобы работать не вызовом по типу окна, а по типу VM и уже будет более менее? А что на счет передачи Vm как аргумент в метод закрытия окна чтобы найти окно такой подход норм?

Ваш код должен быть завязан на типах, а не на объектах. Зачем там передача конкретной VM я не знаю. Я написал вам ответом то, как +- должно это выглядеть, дальше уже подстраивайте под себя.
